# Converting a 50+ column table into 1 much smaller table

Tags: mysql, unpivot

I'm currently dealing with a legacy PLC device which is spitting out data in an annoying MYSQL table. The table structure is:

```
PK | FK | FK | FK | Result1 | Result2 | ... | ResultN
```

As you can imagine, performing any sort of query or join on this is quite cumbersome to write and takes a long time to resolve.

I'd like to setup an automatic select -> insert statement to pull the data and put it into a more appropriate table

```
PK | FK | FK | FK | Result Number | Result Value
```

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on how to pull the column names so I know what to populate the `Result Number` column with, as well as then how to cross-multiply across the table to make sure each new row has all the required keys for each value.

Comment: You will find already a lot of answers for your case here, see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944417/mysql-convert-column-to-row-pivot-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by using code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359345/transposing-dynamic-columns-to-rows which is still valid 5 years later. Basically, I used a dynamic SQL statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select col1, col2, ''',
      c.column_name,
      ''' as Measurement, ',
      c.column_name,
      ' as Result 
      from housings
      where col1 > 0'

    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  )  into @sql
FROM information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'housings'
  and c.column_name not in ('col1', col2)
order by c.ordinal_position;



SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('Insert into unpivoted_parts_table(col1, col2, Measurement, Result)
            select col1, col2, Measurement, Result
           from
           (', @sql, ') x  order by id');



PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need N `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statements.  A one-time tedious task.

Answer (score 1):

If it is required to store rows with the same set of FKs consecutively on disk (which is not unreasonable), you would probably prefer to do the conversion in a single statement sorting all the rows by the FKs.

You can do that using a [numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751318/creating-a-numbers-table-in-mysql):

```
INSERT INTO
  YourResultTable (FK1, FK2, FK3, ResultNumber, ResultValue)
SELECT
  t.FK1,
  t.FK2,
  t.FK3,
  n.Number AS ResultNumber,
  CASE n.Number
    WHEN 1 THEN t.Result1
    WHEN 2 THEN t.Result2
    ...
    WHEN N THEN t.ResultN
  END AS ResultValue
FROM
  YourTable AS t
  CROSS JOIN Numbers AS n
WHERE
  n.Number BETWEEN 1 AND the_N_value
ORDER BY
  t.FK1    ASC,
  t.FK2    ASC,
  t.FK3    ASC,
  n.Number ASC
;
```

In case the source table is too big to be converted in one go, you can do that in batches several (hundreds? thousands?) FK sets at a time, making sure each group of rows with the same FKs is inserted unseparated. A filter on e.g. FK1 could achieve that, so the first time it would be

```
...
WHERE
  n.Number BETWEEN 1 AND the_N_value
  AND t.FK1 <= some_value
...
```

then the next time

```
...
WHERE
  n.Number BETWEEN 1 AND the_N_value
  AND t.FK1 > some_value AND t.FK1 <= some_other_value
...
```

and so on. This will perhaps be even more tedious than [Rick James's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198792/6965) because you might not always know in how many batches to do this split and what values to use for the filtering. But if storing same FKs consecutively is a requirement, this is one way to meet it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement, taking advantage of 2 (not widely known) MySQL functions:

- [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) - Given a list of values passed (your columns), returns the first non-`NULL` value.
- [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) - The first argument is the value to find, the result is its position in the list of following arguments.

I can't write your query for you, but it should look like this, approximately:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (val, num)
    SELECT
    @v := COALESCE(col1, col2, col3...),
    FIELD(@v, col1, col2, col3...)
    FROM old_table;
```

I used a [user variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) (`@v`) just for readability, to avoid repeating the whole `COALESCE()`.

Note that my example requires that columns are `NULL` when no value is set. If you use something else instead (say, an empty string), you will need to specify this for each column:

```
NULLIF(col1, '')
```